# Failed to connect to MySQL: (2002) No such file or directoryError: // MariaDB issue?

Tags: debian, mysql, mariadb, error-logging

--Apologies in advance. Not a coder, but have gotten this far with the assistance of v helpful people on forums such as this--

I've had a VM instance running on GCP with no issues for a couple of years.
Just received a non-tech server error message (5xx) from Google Search Console

Restarted the VM - but now the message returns
"Failed to connect to MySQL: (2002) No such file or directoryError:"

Ran `sudo systemctl start mariadb`
returned the following:

```
mariadb.service - MariaDB database server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mariadb.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2022-03-23 15:16:45 UTC; 19s ago
  Process: 1258 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld $MYSQLD_OPTS $_WSREP_NEW_CLUSTER $_WSREP_START_POSITION (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 1169 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c [ ! -e /usr/bin/galera_recovery ] && VAR= ||   VAR=`/usr/bin/galera_recovery`; [ $? -eq 0 ]   && systemctl set-environment _WSREP_START_P
OSITION=$VAR || exit 1 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 1166 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c systemctl unset-environment _WSREP_START_POSITION (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 1163 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/install -m 755 -o mysql -g root -d /var/run/mysqld (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 1258 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Status: "MariaDB server is down"
Mar 23 15:16:45 jinguru-lamp-004 systemd[1]: Starting MariaDB database server...
Mar 23 15:16:45 jinguru-lamp-004 mysqld[1258]: 2022-03-23 15:16:45 139952113873472 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 10.1.26-MariaDB-0+deb9u1) starting as process 1258 ...
Mar 23 15:16:45 jinguru-lamp-004 mysqld[1258]: 2022-03-23 15:16:45 139952113873472 [Warning] Can't create test file /var/lib/mysql/jinguru-lamp-004.lower-test
Mar 23 15:16:45 jinguru-lamp-004 systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Mar 23 15:16:45 jinguru-lamp-004 systemd[1]: Failed to start MariaDB database server.
Mar 23 15:16:45 jinguru-lamp-004 systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Unit entered failed state.
Mar 23 15:16:45 jinguru-lamp-004 systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Have scanned resources online that yielded issues like:

tc.log (tried deleting/renaming - there is nothing on the file)
ntp.drift (not entirely sure how to manage this)

running journalctl - highlighted lines are:

```
Mar 23 15:11:57 localhost kernel: [Firmware Bug]: TSC doesn't count with P0 frequency!
Mar 23 15:11:57 localhost kernel: piix4_smbus 0000:00:01.3: SMBus base address uninitialized - upgrade BIOS or use force_addr=0xaddr
Mar 23 15:12:00 jinguru-lamp-004 ntpd[685]: format error frequency file /var/lib/ntp/ntp.drift
Mar 23 15:12:00 jinguru-lamp-004 ntpd[685]: bind(21) AF_INET6 fe80::4001:aff:fe80:4%2#123 flags 0x11 failed: Cannot assign requested address
Mar 23 15:12:00 jinguru-lamp-004 ntpd[685]: unable to create socket on eth0 (5) for fe80::4001:aff:fe80:4%2#123
Mar 23 15:12:02 jinguru-lamp-004 systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Mar 23 15:12:02 jinguru-lamp-004 systemd[1]: Failed to start MariaDB database server.
Mar 23 15:12:02 jinguru-lamp-004 systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Unit entered failed state.
Mar 23 15:12:02 jinguru-lamp-004 systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Have looked at Q&A like
https://serverfault.com/questions/1045343/cant-start-mariadb-anymore-on-debian-10

But this doesn't seem to solve the issue:
service mysql restart yields:

```
Job for mariadb.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status mariadb.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

Comment: What happens if you try to create a file in `/var/lib`?

Comment: permissions are on 755 
i tried creating test.txt with  permission denied

Comment: @jellybeans - Did you create the test file with the owner of the folder? Any other user except the owner of the folder cannot create a file in the folder with 755 permissions

Comment: I can create the test file by giving the owner permission using:
sudo chown -R  user:user  /var/lib
on the SSH window

Comment: I also just downloaded the error.log file in /var/log/mysql and discovered the following:

2022-03-23 14:03:53 139716939256384 [ERROR] InnoDB: Could not find a valid tablespace file for 'jdb000/downloads'. 
2022-03-23 14:03:53 139716939256384 [ERROR] InnoDB: Tablespace open failed for '"jdb000"."downloads"', ignored.
2022-03-23 14:03:53 7f1262889240  InnoDB: Operating system error number 13 in a file operation.
InnoDB: The error means mysqld does not have the access rights to
InnoDB: the directory.

Which is strange as i've not touched anything (in a very very long time)